DataGridView I want to format the date in the tenth cell from the current date 2024-11-18T10:59:00.000+0000 to 2024-11-18
DataGridView I want to format the date in the tenth cell
from 2024-11-18T10:59:00.000+0000
to 2024-11-18
The history appears to be very long and all I want is history.
The date is showing too long and what I want is just the date
Column number in cell 10
I tried using this it didn't work
For i = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
Next


fwiw, .Cells(10) is the eleventh cell, since arrays start counting at 0.

You can on form load make
 DataGridView1.Columns(10).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd"

This will change the style of the date column
And you apply it like this in the class of your and FORM_Load
Private Sub Start_frm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'add datasource
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset_table.Tables(0)

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 110
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 115
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format =  "yyyy-MM-dd"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 135
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width = 125
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format =  "yyyy-MM-dd"
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Width = 110
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format =  "yyyy-MM-dd"
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Width = 110
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format =  "yyyy-MM-dd"
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).Width = 110
    DataGridView1.Columns(8).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    DataGridView1.Columns(8).Width = 110
    DataGridView1.Columns(10).Width = 120
    DataGridView1.Columns(11).Width = 110

End Sub

if your datasource is string
you can split the value at the tenth character
 For i = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value.ToString.Substring(0, 10)

 Next


I tried that but it didn't work.

you make it in the Form_load only once not for every column

The only possible reason why the date is shown like this: 2024-11-18T10:59:00.000+0000, without a pre-existing format expression, is because the data source is a string, so formatting doesn't apply
